# Froala 405 (Method Not Allowed) while uploading image - Laravel

Tags: laravel, editor, wysiwyg, froala

I'm currently trying to implement a wysiwyg editor for the first time. I'm struggling trying to upload images because it sends me a 405 (Method Not Allowed).

```
        // Set the image upload parameter.
        imageUploadParam: 'image_param',

        // Set request type.
        imageUploadMethod: 'POST',

        // Set the image upload URL.
        imageUploadURL: '/image/post',

        // Additional upload params.
        imageUploadParams: {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },

        // Set max image size to 5MB.
        imageMaxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,

        // Allow to upload PNG and JPG.
        imageAllowedTypes: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
```

and my route is:

```
Route::post('image/post', 'Admin\NewsController@uploadImage')->name('admin.news.image.store');
```

So, I don't understand why I'm getting that 405 (Method not allowed) if I'm using a POST route and saying POST on the Froala request too.

Comment: Your missing CSRF token in the header.  Some details on how to set this up here:

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the CSRF in the header ( not in as a parameter ).  Some details here:

[Laravel / vue-froala-wysiwyg integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544808/laravel-vue-froala-wysiwyg-integration/58530571#58530571)